# Ad - Hoc сети. Технология ради технологии или перспективное решение?

Tags: администрирование, сеть

В рамках своей научной работы пишу систему моделирования для Ad - Hoc сетей. Меня интересует вопрос, сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с данной технологией по долгу работы и в каких целях? Какие нюансы и сложности возникают при развертке данных сетей? Знает ли кто-нибудь реальные проекты, которые так или иначе использовали Ad - Hoc сети? Или программное обеспечение так или иначе работающее с Ad - Hoc сетями?

Информации по этой теме не так много, хотелось бы услышать мнение о перспективности данной технологии от коллег.

Comment: В самом деле интересный вопрос. Особенно при обилии устройств с wi-fi.